# How to get values of input field from one page to another?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to download data displayed after search query.

```
require 'conn/Session.php';
require 'conn/MySQL.php';
require_once("includes/paging.inc.php");
require_once("classes/class.SiteManager.php");
$dbcon =  new MySQL();
$siteObj =  new SiteManager();
require 'conn/checkSession.php';
$paging = new Pager;
$id = $_POST['id'];
$from=$_REQUEST['$s'];
$to=$_REQUEST['$v'];
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `reports` WHERE date BETWEEN "$from" and "$to"' ); 

echo $result;
die();
```

Here I'm not able to get value of `$from` and `$to`, where `$v` and `$s` are input fields for dates at search query

Comment: `$_REQUEST['$v'];` what's $v? and $s

Comment: i am running two queries on different pages one is for view the sorted data and one is to download the sorted data $s and $v are values for the input value of dates in search query

Comment: they are passed to this page via post or get request?

Comment: the values will be like $_REQUEST['s']; and $_REQUEST['v']; try it and let me know if it worked

Comment: not working values are empty

Comment: print_r($_POST);die and check the varibables

Comment: its array();   no values inside array

Comment: means you do not post the values from the previous page

Comment: i had post there is search query
 
 
 $s=$_POST['date'][1];
$v=$_POST['date'][2];




 
 $sql="select * from  reports where date between '$s' and '$v'";
 
 
 
 
 <form method="get" action="#">
                    <input type="date" name="date[1]" id="date" />
<input type="date" name="date[2]" id="date" />            
                <input class="button"  type="submit" name="search" value="Search" >

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'conn/Session.php';
require 'conn/MySQL.php';
require_once("includes/paging.inc.php");
require_once("classes/class.SiteManager.php");
$dbcon =  new MySQL();
$siteObj =  new SiteManager();
require 'conn/checkSession.php';
$paging = new Pager;
$id = $_POST['id'];
$from=$_GET['s']; // $_POST['s']
$to=$_GET['v']; // $_POST['v']
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reports WHERE date BETWEEN $from and $to"); 

echo $result;
die();
```

Comment: Can you var_dump $_POST?
Is there any error displayed?

Comment: no error i want to download data displayed by the sort quey and from there i want the values of $ and $v

Comment: Can you show your original search query, how dose it looks like?